# Permission problem with SFTP in FileZilla

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, sudo

Recently, we installed Ubuntu Server on our servers this is very new for us. However, we tried to setup a apache2 server which did work. But the problem is that we can't configure apache and other configure files due the lack of permissions. I found a command for some days ago and gave myself access to "/var/www". But that's the only folder I got permissions to. I forgot what the command was and I can't use root because I don't know the password. I can't remember if I tried to setup any. I am the only user on the machine so I got admin permissions but need root. So what I need help with is to give myself access to the whole server. Mostly "/etc/apache2" but the whole server would be better. Anyways, how do I give myself permissions for this and how do I enable root? All sudo commands tells me this "
sudo: must be setuid root".

Answer (score 1):

isn't sudo what you're looking for? In Ubuntu, when you want to get root privileges, you must run "sudo command"... or "sudo su" (there is also "sudo -s", and I think the difference is with environment variables, but I don't remember now) if you really want a root session. The password is your user password.

Try to check the owner of the directories... If I remember correctly, in ubuntu, apache creates a user and group of his own, and that only has access to it's own directories.

EDIT: I believe your only way to fix this is to boot with a Linux live disc and mount your Ubuntu file system there to fix the permissions and owner of the sudo binary (and maybe sudoers file). These commands should do it:

```
sudo chown root:root /mnt/yourfs/usr/bin/sudo
sudo chmod 4755 /mnt/yourfs/usr/bin/sudo
sudo chown root:root /mnt/yourfs/etc/sudoers
sudo chmod 440 /mnt/yourfs/etc/sudoers
```

The leading 4 in first chmod is to set the setuid special permission: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html

Comment: When I type "sudo -s" or "sudo su" it says 
sudo: must be setuid root.

Comment: Was this information originally on the topic? I need to visit my oftalmologist. hehe. Sorry for that. Googling for this error message I found a number of threads. Seems like the problem might be with the permissions of the sudo binary. But you would need to use a recovery/live disc to change that. Have you tried it? For reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930151

Comment: Hmm, the only way to solve it is to use the recovery/live disc? I would have to ask the guy who hosts this for me. He doesn't understand how to use the disc and boot up. I would have to go and do it manually again then?

Comment: You should probably check if there's really something wrong with the sudo binary... "ls -l /usr/bin/sudo" should result in something like that: "-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root ..." (that's what it appears here). I believe the important part is the s permission.

Comment: It says -rwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 69708 Feb 27  2013 /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: Well, there's definitely something wrong here... your sudo binary belongs to www-data user, which I believe is an user created for apache. And also, it lacks the "s" bit. I tried a few things here and I believe the only way to fix it is really using a live disc. This is because you can't change owner of a file to root. See here why: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1276888#p1276888. I updated my answer to what I believe is your only way out.